How to wait for AWS RDS to be in stopped state using CLI?
I can see that it is possible to wait for an AWS RDS to be available or deleted using the CLI:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/db-instance-available.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/db-instance-deleted.html

But what if I want to wait for the RDS to be in stopped state? How do I do this since there is no db-instance-stopped option for the aws rds wait CLI command?

Poll the describe instance endpoint and check the state field.
